# JavaScript Memory heap error on SSR build

Tags: javascript, angular, out-of-memory, heap-memory, server-side-rendering

Is there a parameter or command to optimize memory while running an Angular SSR build? This command I am using is as follows:

```
npm run universal:build:q1
```

Where `q1` is the environment name.

I am getting a JavaScript memory heap error with `max_old_space_size` as 4096. Increasing or decreasing this value doesn't help. So can the memory be optimized to run the build?

Comment: What causes the memory heap error? Maybe this could help: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10897

Comment: Which command line did you use to increase memory?